# ui-router with customer controller and ng-strict-di

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

so, following best practice I've started using ng-strict-di. It's worked well so far, but I have hit the following problem using ui-router

```
// nested list with custom controller
.state('dashboard.list', {
    url: '/list',
    templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard-list.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
    }
})
```

this causes angular to barf with the "Error: error:strictdi
Explicit annotation required" error.

I know that I should be using the inline bracket notation, or $inject, but obviously can't put it in this code as is.

I was thinking that I could declare the controller in another part of the script, with $inject and then just reference it in the code ?

```
function GoodController1($scope) {
}

GoodController1.$inject = ["$scope"];
```

and then

```
// nested list with custom controller
.state('dashboard.list', {
    url: '/list',
    templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard-list.html',
    controller: GoodController1
})
```

would this work ? Are there any problems with this approach ?

Comment: *would this work ?*: do it, and test, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: lol. thanks ;) I have just tried it and it seems to work ..

Answer (score 2):

There are no problems, with this approach. I am using typescript, and the generated syntax of controlelr class is almost the same as yours.

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kx7OuOT2HHUL7TnfO4uM?p=preview)

```
...
// the contoller funciton to be instantiated
// by angular using new 
var GoodController1 = function($scope){ 
  $scope.title = "good title";
};
// set of dependencies
// (in typescript that would be a static property)
GoodController1.$inject = ["$scope"];

// before angular 2.0, this is the must
// we still have to register controller in the module
app
  .controller('GoodController1', GoodController1)
...
```

and later in state:

```
.state('good', {
      url: "/good",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: "GoodController1",
  })
```

check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kx7OuOT2HHUL7TnfO4uM?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for the feedback and code. It does seem to work for me.

Comment: That is bit of a joke ;) check some blogs/videos ... angular 2.0 will not have controllers, no modules, no scope... but that is far from now ;) YOU SHOULD observe this one for sure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNmWybAyBHI ;)